# My texture keeps showing up white on screen

Tags: opengl, textures

I cant seem to load an image and use it as a texture to my program: the image is 512*512 in size and i dont know what im doing wrong, can someone help me?

Main function:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  glutInit (&argc, argv);
  glutInitWindowSize (800,600);
  glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutCreateWindow ("CS248 GLUT example");
  glutDisplayFunc (display);
  glutReshapeFunc (reshape);
  glutMainLoop ();
  return 0;
}
```

The display function:

```
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    texture = LoadTexture("space.bmp");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(-20.0,-20.0,0);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(-20.0, 20.0, 0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, 0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex3f(20.0, -20.0, 0.0);   
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

So, i call here the loadtexture function to an GLuint texture, this way:

```
GLuint LoadTexture( const char* texture )
{
    GLuint textureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture( texture, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS ); 
    glGenTextures(1,&textureID);
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT );

    return textureID;
}
```

Reshape function:

```
void reshape(GLsizei w, GLsizei h) {
glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-20.0f, 20.0f, -20.0f, 20.0f, -20.0f, 20.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Includes,etc:

```
#include <glut.h>
#include <SOIL.h>

GLuint texture;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GLuint textureID = SOIL_load_OGL_texture( texture, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO, SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS ); 
glGenTextures(1,&textureID);
```

`SOIL_load_OGL_texture` *creates* an OpenGL texture object. Generating a *new* one (which is what `glGenTextures` does) after already creating one is counter-productive.

Ditch that line, and you'll probably be OK.

However, you should *not* be reloading the texture on every display. You should be creating that texture once, during initialization, then just using the texture with a `glBindTexture` call.